How to pass in a method for different purposes?
I thought this may have been easy enough but doesnt seem so (might be that i need to learn this)
Here is some code i have working as an Extension for one of my types
public static IMySpecialClass[]? MyMultipleFunction(this string[]? values, float line)
{
    if (values == null) return null;
 
    List<IMySpecialClass> listClass = [];
 
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        listClass.Add(v.XXXX(line));
    }
 
    return [.. listClass];
}

I have this method but all i want to do is change/pass in the method that is called in the foreach loop
listClass.Add(v.XXXX(line));

the XXXX is the method i want to change depending on which function i want to execute.
XXXX is of string IMySpecialClass type a void so i cant figure out a way to pass in or state which function i want to use depending on my requirements?
I know i can copy and paste the code and change the XXXX method and name the function different but is there a way to achieve this without copy/paste?
I read up on dynamic types but i feel i need some example to fill in some missing knowledge so be great if someone can show how this can be achieved (if possible) and maybe some reference for me to refer to at a later stage?
Edit
The current code after adding Action to the signature
public static IMySpecialClass[]? MyMultipleFunction(this string[]? values, float line, Func<string, float, IMySpecialClass> func)
{
    if (values == null) return null;
 
    List<IMySpecialClass> listClass = [];
 
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        listClass.Add(func(v.XXXX(line)));
    }
 
    return [.. listClass];
}

At present returns the error
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'arg2' of 'Action<string, float>'
If i remove the float paramter
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'IMySpecialClass' to 'string'

XXXX is most likely coming from (IMySpecialClass) which the third party vendor have implemented in their own way. Whenever i use XXXX it works as intended using the types and values passed in

Edit the question to add more information. Add the actual code too. What you describe is easy using LINQ's Select and a method that generates instances that implement IMySpecialClass based on a string and float value. You can't create interface instances though, so what kind of class do you want to create? XXXX is of string type is a contradiction - XXXX is a method, and string is sealed so nothing can inherit from it

Post something we can take, compile and test so we can fix it. Random changes won't fix anything. func expects 2 parameters but your code doesn't pass them. Never mind that the errors complain about an Action, not Func. There are already two good working answers that only need a few extra lines to run, one defining the concrete class and a method that creates it from arguments.

You do not need this complex extension method. You can just use LINQ:
string[] values = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
IMySpecialClass[] result = values.Select(v => SomeMethod(v, line)).ToArray();

This will apply the method SomeMethod to each element of the values array. The results will be stored in a new array.

If I understood correctly, you can pass an Func<string, float, IMySpecialClass>, as in:
public static IMySpecialClass[]? MyMultipleFunction(this string[]? values, float line, Func<string, float, IMySpecialClass> func)
{
    ...
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        listClass.Add(func(v, line));
    }
    ...
}

And call it like this:
var strings = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
Func<string, float, IMySpecialClass> func = CreateMySpecialClass;
strings.MyMultipleFunction(1f, func));

static IMySpecialClass CreateMySpecialClass(string str, float line)
{
    ...
}

Of course, there must be some CreateMySpecialClass method.

This is close to what im after but i get the error There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'arg2' of 'Action<string, float>' when adding func to the foreach loop

Sorry, I updated the answer

Using the code as is, i still have the same error There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'arg2' of 'Action<string, float>. I then remove the float from Func but then it errors with Argument 1: cannot convert from 'IMySpecialClass' to 'string ? Rememeber XXXX methods have one param passed in

@KeithViking post your code instead of describing it. LINQ's Select already does what you want, although constructing a list with an original capacity reduces allocations. The signature of a function that creats an object that implements IMySpecialClass from a string and float is Func<string,float,IMySpecialClass>. It's easy to pass such a method to Select.

The edit doesn't explain anything more, there's no XXXX method. And the complaint about converting string to an interface means the method doesn't do what you assume. You can't convert a random string to a class. At some point you have to call new ThatSpecialClass

I edited my comment about the method being used which is of IMySpecialClass - that was my mistake i overlooked that part..... @RicardoPeres my apologies for the incorrect info provided originally

@KeithViking please post the missing code so we can understand what you want. Converting a string to a class won't happen by itself. Perhaps you're trying to return a type's name? Or the contents of a class? We can't guess how the string banana 43 is supposed to be converted to a record Fruit(string name,float weight):IMySpecialClass;

Under edit i have added the current code i have. I have edited the mistake and striking through the original text

There's no new code. Without XXXX it's impossible to help. That's where the problem is.
